# cannot fetch libraries for "Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool" error on Ubuntuo 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

Installing android studio gives "Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool" error

Then I run: sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6

Then:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

  account-plugin-windows-live libapparmor-perl libmbim-glib0 libqmi-glib0
  libupstart1 python-colorama python-colorama-whl python-distlib
  python-distlib-whl python-html5lib python-html5lib-whl python-setuptools-whl
  python-six-whl python-wheel usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cpp-4.8 g++-4.8 gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base lib32gcc1 lib32tinfo5 libasan0
  libatomic1 libc6-i386 libgcc-4.8-dev libgfortran3 libgomp1 libitm1
  libquadmath0 libstdc++-4.8-dev libstdc++6 libtsan0
Suggested packages:
  gcc-4.8-locales g++-4.8-multilib gcc-4.8-doc libstdc++6-4.8-dbg
  gcc-4.8-multilib libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg
  libasan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg libstdc++-4.8-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lib32bz2-1.0 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6 lib32tinfo5 lib32z1
  libc6-i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cpp-4.8 g++-4.8 gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base libasan0 libatomic1 libgcc-4.8-dev
  libgfortran3 libgomp1 libitm1 libquadmath0 libstdc++-4.8-dev libstdc++6
  libtsan0
14 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 277 not upgraded.
Need to get 33,9 MB/34,2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 15,4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libitm1 amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libgomp1 amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libquadmath0 amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libgfortran3 amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libasan0 amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libatomic1 amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libtsan0 amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main g++-4.8 amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main gcc-4.8 amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main cpp-4.8 amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libstdc++-4.8-dev amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libgcc-4.8-dev amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main gcc-4.8-base amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libstdc++6 amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libc6-i386 amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.7
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main lib32stdc++6 amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libc6-i386 amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.7
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libitm1_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libgomp1_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libquadmath0_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libgfortran3_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libasan0_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libatomic1_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libtsan0_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/g++-4.8_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/gcc-4.8_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/cpp-4.8_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libstdc++-4.8-dev_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libgcc-4.8-dev_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/gcc-4.8-base_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libstdc++6_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.7_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/lib32stdc++6_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.140.100.100 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

trying with --fix-missing also does not work.

Comment: try: apt-get update

Comment: did it, "not found"s continues